# Different rendering of first item from rest of array

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3.2, zurb-foundation

Attempting to applying Zurb foundation tabs to an array generated by a rails 3.2 application as follows:

```
  <dl class="tabs" data-tab>
    <% @open_dates.first do |open_date| %>
      <dd class="active"><a href="#<%= l(open_date, :format => :day) %>"><%= l(open_date, :format => :day) %></a></dd>
    <% end %>
    <% @open_dates.drop(1) do |open_date| %>
      <dd><a href="#<%= l(open_date, :format => :day) %>"><%= l(open_date, :format => :day) %></a></dd>
    <% end %>
  </dl>
```

The first item needs to have a class defined as `active`  to render proeprly in HTML.  Using the [ruby array methods](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html) of `first` and `drop (1)` the HTML output is entirely blank

```
  <dl class="tabs" data-tab>
  </dl>
```

The array is not empty as using `each` does output the data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why your implementation doesn't work, but if you say `each` worked, you can do this with `each` and even simplify your code with it:

```
  <dl class="tabs" data-tab>
    <% @open_dates.each_with_index do |open_date, index| %>
      <dd class='<%= "active" if index == 0 %>'>
        <a href="#<%= l(open_date, :format => :day) %>"><%= l(open_date, :format => :day) %></a>
      </dd>
    <% end %>
  </dl>
```